# escalonamiento de matriz en python

Tags: python, matrices, numpy

tengo problemas al intentar escalonar una matriz 5x5. En primer lugar hice que una línea nula fuera a la última fila de la matriz (funcionó), luego intenté hacer que una fila que tuviera el mayor índice quedara abajo de la que tuviera un índice menor, pero en la línea:

```
if pivos_indices[i] > pivos_indices[linha_aux] and linha_aux < 5 and i < 5:
```

del código, el compilador advierte que el índice de la lista está fuera del intervalo, pero no sé por qué (ese es el problema). A continuación sigue el código:

```
import numpy as np
def buscar_pivo(L):
    if (np.nonzero(L)[0]).size == 0:
        return -1
    else:
        return np.nonzero(L)[1][0]

def encontrar_pivos_indices(mat):
    pivos = []
    for i in range(5):
        pivos.append(buscar_pivo(np.array(mat[i])))
    return pivos

mat = np.matrix([[0,5,2,7,8],[8,10,4,14,16],[0,0,0,0,0],[2,6,10,16,22],[3,5,8,9,15]]).astype(float)
print("Matriz original:\n",mat,"\n")

pivos_indices = encontrar_pivos_indices(mat)

linha_aux = 0
for i in range(5):
    linha_aux = linha_aux + 1
    if pivos_indices[i] == -1 and linha_aux < 5 and i < 5:
        m = mat.tolist()
        (m[i],m[linha_aux]) = (m[linha_aux],m[i])
        mat = np.matrix(m)
        pivos_indices = encontrar_pivos_indices(mat)

print(mat,"\n")

linha_aux = 0
for i in range(5): 
    linha_aux = linha_aux + 1
    if pivos_indices[i] > pivos_indices[linha_aux] and linha_aux < 5 and i < 5:
        m = mat.tolist()
        (m[i],m[linha_aux]) = (m[linha_aux],m[i])
        mat = np.matrix(m)
        pivos_indices = encontrar_pivos_indices(mat)

print(mat)
```

Comment: sí, los cambios en la matriz deben ser hechos en las líneas, para eslacarla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se encuentra en:

```
for i in range(5): 
    linha_aux = linha_aux + 1
    if pivos_indices[i] > pivos_indices[linha_aux] and linha_aux < 5 and i < 5:
```

Tienes un array de 5 elementos, el valor máximo que alcanza `i` en tu `for` es 4, pero para `i` = 4 **`linha_aux` vale 5 y `pivos_indices[5]` no es válido porque ese índice esta fuera de rango para un array de 5 elementos (en el que el indice máximo es 4)**. `and linha_aux < 5` no sirve de protección porque no llega a evaluarse, ya que la indexación se produce antes de que se evalúe.

Lo lógico es hacer que el `for` itere hasta `len(array) - 1`, en este caso `for i in range(4)`.

Hay una forma más simple de ordenar el array en función del numero de ceros consecutivos iniciales. Valiendonos de tu idea de usar `np.nonzero` podemos usar el array resultante con el indice de los pivotes. Después lo ordenamos y obtenemos los indices de los elementos ordenados (`numpy.argsort`) y por último hacemos un indexado de `mat` con él:

```
import numpy as np

def buscar_pivo(L):
    p = np.nonzero(L)[1]
    if p.size:
        return p[0]
    return L.size

mat = np.matrix([[0,  5,  2,  7,  8],
                 [0,  0,  0, 14, 16],
                 [0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
                 [0,  0, 10, 16, 22],
                 [0,  0,  0,  0,  8]]).astype(float)

res = mat[np.argsort(np.apply_along_axis(buscar_pivo, axis=1, arr=mat))]
print(res)
```

**Salida:**

```
[[  0.   5.   2.   7.   8.]
 [  0.   0.  10.  16.  22.]
 [  0.   0.   0.  14.  16.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   8.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

Para tu ejemplo original obtenemos:

```
>>> mat = np.matrix([[0,  5,  2,  7,  8],
                     [8, 10,  4, 14, 16],
                     [0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
                     [2,  6, 10, 16, 22],
                     [3,  5,  8,  9, 15]]).astype(float)
>>> res = mat[np.argsort(np.apply_along_axis(buscar_pivo, axis=1, arr=mat))]
>>> res  
[[  8.  10.   4.  14.  16.]
 [  2.   6.  10.  16.  22.]
 [  3.   5.   8.   9.  15.]
 [  0.   5.   2.   7.   8.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

---

---

**Edición:**

- La función `buscar_pivo` ha sido modificada para adaptarse a nuestras necesidades. Antes se retornaba -1 si la fila es nula (todos los elementos son 0). El problema es que al ordenar los indices de los pivotes estas filas quedarían las primeras, cuando deben ser las últimas. Por esta razón, en vez de retornar -1 se retorna el tamaño de la fila. Para una matriz de 5 x 5 se retorna 5, dado que el indice máximo es 4, estas líneas siempre quedaran ordenadas al final.
- **`np.apply_along_axis(buscar_pivo, axis=1, arr=mat)`** itera sobre las filas de la matriz `mat` creando un array con las salidas resultado de aplicar la función `buscar_pivo` a cada fila. Es decir, llama a `buscar_pivo` por cada fila, pasando como argumento a la función esa fila y crea un nuevo array con los resultados. El argumento `axis` indica sobre que eje de la matriz vamos a aplicar la función. En una matriz 2d el eje 0 es el eje x (columnas) y el eje 1 es el eje y (filas). En este caso usamos el eje 1 ya que lo que queremos pasar a `buscar_pivo` son las filas. Si tenemos un array 3d podemos iterar sobre el eje z con `axis = 3`, y así sucesivamente.  Vamos a verlo con un ejemplo:

  ```
  >>> import numpy as np
  >>> array = np.array[[1,  2],
                       [5,  9],
                       [-4, 3]]

  # Funcción estúpida que retorna la suma de los elementos de un array:

  >>> def suma(arr):
          return np.sum(arr)

  # Suma de los elementos de cada columna:
  >>> s = np.apply_along_axis(suma, axis=0, arr=array)
  >>> s
  array([ 2, 14])

  # Suma de los elementods de cada fila:
  >>> s = np.apply_along_axis(suma, axis=1, arr=array)
  >>> s
  array([ 3, 14, -1])
  ```
- **`np.argsort`** en vez de retornar el array ordenado retorna los indices de esos elementos ordenados.

  ```
  >>> import numpy as np
  >>> array = np.array([4,  2,  1, 5])
  >>> s = array.argsort() 
  >>> s
  array([2, 1, 0, 3]) #Se corresponden con los indices de 1, 2, 4 y 5
  ```
- Por último podemos hacer un indexado de un array pasándole un array de indices:

  ```
  >>> import numpy as np
  >>> array = np.array([4,  2,  1, 5])
  >>> s = array[[3, 0, 1, 2]]
  >>> s
  array([5, 4, 2, 1])
  ```

Comment: Muchas gracias, mucho. Estoy tratando de resolver este problema desde hace semanas, ahora voy a estudiar sobre esta nueva función. Muchas gracias

Comment: Entendí ese razonamiento, pero ahora necesito buscar ese valor del índice de la línea nula. Escribí una respuesta, mira, por favor!

Comment: @JKSevilla Todo bien, muchas gracias.

Comment: @AndrewJhonatan me acabo de dar cuenta pero el +1 no es necesario, basta con `return L.size`, ha sido un lapsus. De esta forma, toda linea nula retornara `mat[0].size`

Comment: @JKSevilla Yo realmente soy nuevo aquí, todavía no sé muy bien cómo funciona. Muchas gracias por sacar mis dudas y ayudarme. ¡Muchas gracias mismo!

Comment: @JKSevilla He buscado sobre las funciones np.argsort () y np.apply_along_axis (), pero no entiendo el funciomento del argumento "axis", me podría explicar, en esa matriz?

Comment: @AndrewJhonatan `axis` indica sobre que eje de la matriz vamos a ir aplicando la función. El el eje 0 (eje x) son las columnas y el eje 1 (eje y) se corresponde con las filas. He editado la respuesta, mira al final de ella a ver si lo he medio explicado,,, :)

Comment: @JKSevilla Ahora no tengo dudas, muchas gracias. No tienes ni idea de cuánto me has ayudado y cuánto estoy agradecido.